# pdf parse to text in java

Tags: java, pdf, ocr, pdf-parsing

I have an Arabic PDF, and I want to parse it into text document using Java. I have tried many times, and the English words parse successfully but the Arabic words don't.

Can anyone recommend a solution that will convert the Arabic words properly as well?

Comment: See these: http://www.prasannatech.net/2009/01/convert-pdf-text-parser-java-api-pdfbox.html

Comment: which library are you using to read the pdf file?

Comment: pdfbox not good for parsing arabic pdf

Comment: i tried pdfbox and iText and Apache plug-ins they not work probably like i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) for pdf manipulation using Java. It supports Arabic too.

Comment: i tried iText it create a pdf not convert it to text please if you have ahelp give me

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries that come to mind. [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) will all more or less solve your problem. Although, I must put in a word for Tika, as it supports language detection, and can also handle other document types too.

Comment: i tried all the libraries you mentioned ,they cant parse arabic pdf,apache tika parse arabic but not all the pdf files i think that the pdf is encoded or security on it i cant understand because also when i want to shadow the words it cant shadow it successfully ,pleeeeeeeeeeeease help me

Comment: If a PDF files has the right to extract the text removed (This can be controlled for each file), no software will be able to help you.
The current settings of a PDF can be found be opening the file in the Adobe Reader an pressing Crtl-D (or goning to the document properties using the menu).

Comment: thanx for your help ,but i want to know what is the property i should change in the pdf properties to make it selectable ????

Comment: In IText you would set the [ALLOW_COPY](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#ALLOW_COPY) permission using the [setEncryption](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#setEncryption(byte[],%20byte[],%20int,%20int)) method of PdfWriter. If you are editing existing PDFs that are already encrypted, you need the current password first.